# ReverseProxy Wildcard?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass, rhel5

Is it possible to have a wildcard for a reverse Proxy using ProxyPass?

I've seen similar config below for ProxypassMatch, so I tried to model it off of that using just proxypass

ProxyPass ^/retirement-readiness-savings(.*)$ http://prod-domain-com-2018.azurewebsites.net/retirement-readiness-savings-november-2018/$1

Issue I'm having is with character limits(25) on directory names in our new CMS.

Full URL for example below:
/retirement-readiness-savings-november-2018

For Ex with Reverse Proxy config below:

```
#ProxyPass ^/retirement-readiness-savings(.*)$ http://prod-domain-com-2018.azurewebsites.net/retirement-readiness-savings-november-2018$1
#ProxyPassReverse ^/retirement-readiness-savings(.*)$ http://prod-domain-com-2018.azurewebsites.net/retirement-readiness-savings-november-2018$1
```

So as long as the URL Matches the first 3 words it would still host the same page, ignoring **november-2018**

Only have ProxyPass installed and using httpd.conf to manage ReverseProxy

We are using RHEL 5.11 with mod_proxy module installed

**EDIT:** What I'm trying to do is catch/check the first 25 characters of the directory path, but still map to the full azure path.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me where the 25 char restriction is, but perhaps you want to do something like this?

```
ProxyPass ^/site/(.{1,25}).*$ http://prod-domain-com-2018.azurewebsites.net/site/$1
```

That would capture the first 25 chararcters after `/site/` and then use that in the mapping, for example, a request for this:

```
/site/retirement-readiness-savings-some-thing-or-other
```

... would map to this:

```
http://prod-domain-com-2018.azurewebsites.net/site/retirement-readiness-savi
```

('retirement-readiness-savi' == 25 char limit)

Comment: Thank you for that guzzijason, The Character limit is set in the CSM for directory names. I like what oyu have mentioned above what I'm trying to do is catch the first 25 characters of the directory name but still map to the full URL.